# How do I make a document with two cover pages on InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I need to create a document with two single cover pages, when two page display is enabled. I've attached an example layout below. Is this possible?

```
   1
   2
3  4
5  6
6  7
```

Comment: Where is the example? I see just the numbers '1 2 3 4 5 6 6 7'.

Comment: I've fixed your formatting because it was displaying as a single row of numbers. Look at the preview before posting!

Answer (score 0):

In the Pages window drop-down menu, uncheck "Allow Document Pages to Shuffle"

[image]

You should then be able to place pages as you want:

[image]